# comparison operation

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unsigned and signed comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384911/unsigned-and-signed-comparison)
>   [A riddle (in C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611724/a-riddle-in-c)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};
int main()
{
   int d = -1;
   if (d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS)
      printf("of course -1 is less than %d",TOTAL_ELEMENTS);
   else
      printf("how on earth");
   return 0;
}
```

answer is:::Output of the above program is : how on earth

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950051/confused-about-c-macro-expansion-and-integer-arithmetic

Answer (score 3):

When you perform mixed signed vs. unsigned comparison (where signed type is not larger than unsigned one), the comparison is performed in *unsigned* domain, i.e. the signed operand is implicitly converted to unsigned type.

In your case `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` has type `size_t`, which is unsigned. That means that your `d` is also implicitly converted to `size_t` type. So, your `d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS` is actually interpreted as `(size_t) d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS` or `(size_t) -1 < TOTAL_ELEMENTS`.

`(size_t) -1` is an extremely large positive value. It is actually the largest possible value of type `size_t`. Hence the result you get.

In your case you apparently want a signed comparison. For that you have to explicitly convert the unsigned value to signed type (paying close attention not to cause overflow). For example, this will work "as expected"

```
if (d < (int) TOTAL_ELEMENTS)
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `sizeof_t` is mapped to an *unsigned long* type, so `-1` becomes `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, a rather large *positive* integer. Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS(a) ((int)(sizeof((a))/sizeof(*(a))))
int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};
int main() {
    int d = -1;
    if (d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS(array)) {
        printf("of course -1 is less than %d",TOTAL_ELEMENTS(array));
    } else {
        printf("how on earth");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note how I re-wrote your macro to reference `array` as its parameter, and added a cast to `int` to ensure that comparing to `-1` would bring an expected result.